# How to translate "$before" with get text in get_the_term_list?

Tags: translation, query-string, xgettext

How can I make $before (Books:) a translateable string

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'book', 'Books: ',', ', ' ', '' ); ?>
```

with this method?:

```
<?php the_content(__('Read more...', "ft")); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [**`__()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) function, just as you see in the `the_content()` example:

```
<?php 
echo get_the_term_list( 
    // ID
    $post->ID, 
    // taxonomy
    'book', 
    // Before
    __( 'Books: ', 'ft' ),
    // Separator, see http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7897
    __( ', ' ), 
    // After
    ' ', 
    // Looks like you've added an extra parameter?
    '' 
); 
?>
```

Note 1: <del>I split the word "Books" from the part of the string that (probably) shouldn't need to be translated - i.e. the colon and space.); the two parts of the parameter are concatenated.</del> (*Ed: Per @Toscho's suggestion, I changed this*)

Note 2: Looks like you've added an extra parameter to your call to [`get_the_term_list()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)

Comment: Thanks again Chip! I'm lost between commas, apostrophes and semicolons...

Comment: No worries! That's why I like to break functions down, line-by-line, if they have too many parameters. For me, that makes it easier to follow what I'm defining for each parameter, with the inline comments.

Comment: Chip are you sure about the position of the `: ` (double colon plus space)? This looks probably rather strange untranslated in a RTL language, doesn't it?

Comment: @Toscho: no, actually, I'm not sure. That's why I made the note to point it out. :)

Comment: Okay, I made the [comma](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7897) translatable too. Let's write showcases only. :)

Comment: @Chip, Yes I've accidentally left the extra parameters there, thanks for pointing out!